# Is it possible to modify the html of a link's target after the link has been followed without using a browser add-on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, web

Basically what I want to be able to do is click this [link](https://www.google.com) and have it change the text in all the buttons to "Click me!". This can easily be done with the code below using jQuery 2.1.1 but after searching online I haven't found a way to do it after following the link.

```
$('button').text('Click me!');
```

Is this possible without using a browser extension?

Comment: After following the link, are you still on the same page? If so, has the page reloaded?

Comment: No. After following the link you are now on a newly loaded https://www.google.com

Comment: So those links no longer exist? Or are you trying to change the content of the links on Google.com?

Comment: I'm trying to change the HTML of https://www.google.com when I access https://www.google.com by clicking MY link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. Your javascript is wiped and reloaded from the server with each page load. That means when you load Google.com, you only have access to whatever information/javascript that Google chooses to send you. This is for security concerns, otherwise it would be very easy for site designers to infect client browsers with malicious javascript that, for example, spies on all client activity after leaving the infecting site.

Comment: I thought this would be a problem. Thanks so much for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to grab all your buttons and iterate over each, setting the text.

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

[].forEach.call(buttons, function(button) {
  button.textContent = 'Click me!';
});
```

EDIT: If you want to iterate with a for-loop, you can do:

```
for (var i = 0, l = buttons.length; i < l; i++) {
  buttons[i].textContent = 'Click me!';
}
```